# Attribute <Border> around a <TextBlock> bug

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, border, textblock

Here i am because I have a little problem. I want to add an border around my textblock. This is my current script (xaml):

```
<Grid>
    <Border Visibility="Visible" Width="1000" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" Foreground="Blue" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="28.96" Width="980"><Run Language="fr-fr" Text="Fiche détails de la capitalisation"/></TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,49.05,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run Language="fr-fr" Text="édité le:"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="390,49.05,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run Language="fr-fr" Text="Rafraichissement des données:"/></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

My problem is: even if i set the border property to the first textblock, it's applied to my whole Grid, and i haven't found why.

Is somebody know why?

Thanks in Advance.
Florian SELVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is 1 text box on first line and 2 on second. unless you want to define your grid columns and rows you will have to use stackpanel and dock panel

the following by setting the grid width you control everything. All you need to change if you want spaceing in between the Edit and Refresh is a Top Margin on the dock panel someting like `Margin="0,20,0,0"` and if ou want space on the detail textblock and the border you should put a `Padding` on the border to prevent anything inside coming closer to value set.

```
<Grid Width="500">
        <StackPanel>
            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap"><Run Language="fr-fr" Text="Fiche détails de la capitalisation"/></TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run Language="fr-fr" Text="édité le:"/></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"><Run Language="fr-fr" Text="Rafraichissement des données:"/></TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer franck. I'll keep this solution in case of the canvas one doesn't work in the future. Greetings.

Comment: Only to make sure, you may use this to help you but still highly suggest you look some tutorial or small help file on Grid and `GridRowDefinition` / `GridColumnDefinition`

Comment: I'm doing a little windows phone application on which i use GridRowDefinition and GridColumnDefinition, i'm just not that used to do it on WPF

Answer (score 4):

You haven't defined any rows or columns in your `Grid`. It technically only has 1 column and 1 row, and your `Border` applies to that single row/column, so it appears to surround the entire `Grid`.

Since you're explicitly positioning your elements anyway, try replacing `<Grid>` with `<Canvas>`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this solution works perfectly even if i use several border attributes.

Answer (score 2):

as a workaround in your current scenario try this way, I have moved the placement properties to the border instead of underlying textblock

```
<Grid>
    <Border Visibility="Visible" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="28.96" Width="980">
        <TextBlock Visibility="Visible" Foreground="Blue" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap"><Run Language="fr-fr" Text="Fiche détails de la capitalisation"/></TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,49.05,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run Language="fr-fr" Text="édité le:"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="390,49.05,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run Language="fr-fr" Text="Rafraichissement des données:"/></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: this is a bad way to do it. At that point he would be better off using a canvas

Comment: @Franck actually this suggestion was based on the OP's current approach, however even by using canvas he may still need to set similar properties to place the border correctly inside the canvas. So I though it is worth sharing. As a matter of fact I also up-voted the other answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it and it works, but i think it isn't very effective with the margin.

Comment: Margin inside grid is not a good way to do it. i understand his answer building around your request, it works for you but you should really check about using row and columns like @Grant said.

Comment: +1 for considering the OP approach :) and still manage to make it work. Kudos !!!